# How to get the imagestream from graphics class

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I want to save the image created from graphics class how to do it?
(if i can get the imagestream then i can do it using below code)

```
    var bmp = Bitmap.FromStream(originalStream);

       // var newImage = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        var img = new Bitmap(bmp, 
                    (int)(bmp.Size.Width / zoomLevel), 
                    (int)(bmp.Size.Height / zoomLevel));

        var g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, (int)CurrentX, (int)CurrentY);
        g.DrawString(Text, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, (float)CurrentTextX, (float)CurrentTextY);




        string originalImagePath = string.Concat(@"Photos/", string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplicationDateTime.Today) + "/" + Session[Keys.UserId], "/", url.Split('/').Last());
        var originalImageamazonResponse = _s3AmazonServices.StoreImage(originalStream, originalImagePath, Configuration.ConfigurationNew.Current.S3Bucket, Configuration.ConfigurationNew.Current.S3AmazonAccessKey, Configuration.ConfigurationNew.Current.S3AmazonSecretKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `img` gets modified with everything you did to the `g` that got created from it. So you should be able to call `img.Save()`.